# take back access right in a custom list after removed

Tags: custom-list, access-denied

I'm site admin, I have full control for the site, but, I've just remove me from a custom list. Now I can not manage it anymore, 
How can I take back the admin control on my custom list?

Comment: as a site collection admin you have full control on the site...how you removed from the list? does the list having the unique permission(stop inheritance)

Comment: yeah, this list has been set to unique permission(stop inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You need a site collection administrator to either add you back with full control permissions or to have the list set to inherit from the parent.